# Extract emails from comma separated file using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

So I purchased an email list in a txt file and of course there's a bunch of email addresses, albeit, they are intermingled with other text that I could care less about. Ultimately, I'd like to extract ONLY the email addresses and save them to a new file. How might I accomplish this using Ruby?

I'm a way off, but I've tried:

```
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A([\w+\-].?)+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i

emails = "id,pwsid,pid,age,sex,domain,orderamount,first_order_amount,cobrand_id,show_lang,profile_type,handle,email
374380696,310579607_70200,g1067409-pct.subregmem,27,1,gmail.com,0,0,0,english,0,parineeti,rishav.kr2055@gmail.com
374380707,310579618_50472,g1067409-pct.subregmem,27,1,gmail.com,0,0,0,english,0,rajuhalchal,hopowertuls@gmail.com
374380708,310579619_86273,g1227112-pct.subposhgay,45,1,mail.com,0,0,21194,english,0,hertsmale2012,herstmale@mail.com
374380712,310579622_52452,p1911455.sub213,46,1,gmail.com,0,0,31384,english,0,anchezchris0360,Sanchezchris03@gmail.com"

emails_split = emails.split(/,/)

def keep_only_email(email)
  email =~ VALID_EMAIL_REGEX
end

keep_only_email(emails_split)
```

Please help,

Cheers!
AP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that is a CSV file, you could parse it like this.

```
require 'csv'    

csv_text = File.read('input.csv')
csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, headers: true)
file = File.open("output.csv", "w")
csv.each do |row|
  file.write("#{row['email']}\n")
end
```

Comment: Does the input file have to be a .csv? or can it be a .txt?

Comment: `.txt` should also work. why don't you give it a try.

Comment: There is no need to do `File.read`, `CSV.parse`, or `File.open/write` here. This can be done w `CSV.open/read`. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by using `CSV` which is part of the ruby standard library. You basically read in the file, grab the values in the column you're looking for and write to out to a new csv.

```
require 'csv'

CSV.open('output.csv', 'w', headers: ['email'], write_headers: true) do |csv|
  CSV.read('input.csv', headers: true).values_at('email').each do |row| 
    csv << row
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use something likes this, provided the data (lines) are always in the same format:

```
    VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A([\w+\-].?)+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i

    lines = "id,pwsid,pid,age,sex,domain,orderamount,first_order_amount,cobrand_id,show_lang,profile_type,handle,email
    374380696,310579607_70200,g1067409-pct.subregmem,27,1,gmail.com,0,0,0,english,0,parineeti,rishav.kr2055@gmail.com
    374380707,310579618_50472,g1067409-pct.subregmem,27,1,gmail.com,0,0,0,english,0,rajuhalchal,hopowertuls@gmail.com
    374380708,310579619_86273,g1227112-pct.subposhgay,45,1,mail.com,0,0,21194,english,0,hertsmale2012,herstmale@mail.com
    374380712,310579622_52452,p1911455.sub213,46,1,gmail.com,0,0,31384,english,0,anchezchris0360,Sanchezchris03@gmail.com"

    emails = []
    lines.split("\n").each do |line|
      data = line.split(',')
      emails << data[12] if data[12].match(VALID_EMAIL_REGEX)
    end
```

The emails array will contain all emails.